# How to get MobileConnect keywords?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, query, contact, mobileconnect

Is there a way to get a list of all MobileConnect Keywords created on Marketing Cloud? I use attributes search REST endoint https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes to `MobileConnect Subscriptions.Keyword` of a particular contact and I'm able to result like:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-1234",
    "key": "MobileConnect Subscriptions.Keyword",
    "name": "Keyword",
    "value": "*****-*****-****-1234"
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": "xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-1234",
    "key": "MobileConnect Subscriptions.Keyword",
    "name": "Keyword",
    "value":  "*****-*****-****-4321"
}
```

I can see 2 because this contact subscribe to 2 different keywords. I have a total of 10 keywords created in my MobileConnect. Is there a query or an endpoint I can get all 10 keywords and their values like `*****-*****-****-1234` and `*****-*****-****-4321`, ...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to pull this information via a public REST api route provided for this purpose. You can get it from the route:

ttps://mc.exacttarget.com/rest/beta/mobile/code/VjlJbGU3bkdMMDJDenQzbDd3ellkQTo4MTow

you need the Legacy token to authenticate against.

This will pull a collection of Keywords under the Code.  You can find the value for the code by looking at the routes and pulling the info.

Comment: I am trying to do this with no luck. Could you help?